# How should I interpret the 'as' in this sentence? Is the 'them' referring to 'foundation' or 'movies?'

Tags: pronouns, as

How should I interpret the 'as' in this sentence? Also, is the word 'them' referring to 'foundation' or 'movies?'

> In the process, they upended decades of established technique for how to make an effect-heavy movie and created the foundation for movies **as** we understand **them** today.

Comment: I made some edits; please make sure that they're OK. (I assume that "toady" should have been "today".)

Comment: I explained this in my answer.

Comment: What is the question in regards to "as"?  What specifically don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 2):

The "them" refers to the movies, because "them" cannot be used with singular objects (only singular people). Foundation is a singular object.

Comment: "Movies as we understand them today" refers to the kind of films we regard as normal and usual today (_effect-heavy_ = with lots of special effects).

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused about the meaning. How do we understand the movies today? Can you express the sentence in a straightforward way?

Comment: The sentence means "movies of today, as opposed to movies of the 1900s".

Comment: Thanks, i think i understand it now.

Answer (score -3):

as: **in the way that we understand them today**

It's just that.

Comment: Believe me: as we understand them today means what I said. **Nothing else**. Please disregard the dv.

Comment: Lambie, learners of English can't understand this simplicity. It's not like **"It's just that"**, they need you to explicate it!

Comment: @SovereignSun Look at what Kate Bunting said above to **explain** it.

Comment: @SovereignSun What Lambie gives here is pretty much the dictionary definition of "as" in this context. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @gotube Nothing's wrong, not my downvotes, but most people like broad and explanatory answers!

Comment: @SovereignSun Some things are just simple.

Comment: @Lambie Absolutely right, but tell this to others )))